Discrepancy between keras metrics and sklearn metrics
I trained a cnn network model using InceptionV3, to classify images for detection of pulmonary tuberculosis in chest x-rays.
The problem was that at the time of training the metrics seemed to be going well. But when evaluating it there is quite a difference.
First use this method evaluate the model using the validation data generator.
## MODEL EVALUATION
loss, accuracy, precision, recall, auc = model.evaluate(valid_generator)
print(f'Loss: {loss}, Accuracy: {accuracy}, Precision: {precision}, Recall: {recall}, AUC: {auc}')

And it gave me the following result:
38/38 [==============================] - 5s 128ms/step - loss: 0.1684 - accuracy: 0.9339 - precision: 0.9978 - recall: 0.8515 - auc: 0.9952
Loss: 0.16840478777885437, Accuracy: 0.9339389204978943, Precision: 0.9977973699569702, Recall: 0.8515037298202515, AUC: 0.9952080845832825

But also evaluate the model using sklearn.metrics through this code:
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
import numpy as np
import sklearn.metrics

##Getting predictions for the validation data set
valid_generator.reset()
Y_pred = model.predict(valid_generator, steps=len(valid_generator), verbose=1)
Y_pred = np.round(Y_pred)

##Convert true labels to array format
Y_true = valid_generator.classes

print("Classification Report:\n", classification_report(Y_true, Y_pred))

# confusion matrix
conf_mat = confusion_matrix(Y_true, Y_pred)
print("Confusion Matrix:\n", conf_mat)

And it gives me this result:
38/38 [==============================] - 5s 130ms/step
Classification Report:
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.57      0.64      0.60       679
           1       0.46      0.39      0.42       532

    accuracy                           0.53      1211
   macro avg       0.51      0.51      0.51      1211
weighted avg       0.52      0.53      0.52      1211

Confusion Matrix:
 [[432 247]
 [325 207]]

Clearly there is a discrepancy between the results of these different evaluation methods, which one is correct?
Compile and train my model as follows:
#InceptionV3
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(299, 299, 3))
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.Precision(), tf.keras.metrics.Recall(), tf.keras.metrics.AUC()])

history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples // train_generator.batch_size,
    validation_data=valid_generator,
    validation_steps=valid_generator.samples // valid_generator.batch_size,
    epochs=50
)

It should be remembered that I am classifying only 2 classes.

I hope you can help me solve this doubt I have. Thanks in advance.
Being able to know what evaluation metrics to use and which ones are correct.

How do you generate the train_generator and the valid_generator? Can you add these datasets' heads? I saw that you set Y_true = valid_generator.classes If the 'classes' column is not the second column in valid_generator right after the image data column, it might explain the discrepancies. evaluate function uses the unpack_x_y_sample_weight function to split the data. and expects columns to be in that order (x, y, sample_weight) and sets None or wrong values if the order is different.
